# context.Database.MigrateAsync() throwing "AspNetRoles" already exists exception

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement the ASP .NET Core Identity with PostgreSQL. I'm also trying to migrate the database programmatically. The code I'm trying to use, looks like this:

```
using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
```

This will be called at the start up at Program.cs. I'm facing this issue where the ASP Identity tables were created but the exception `Npgsql.PostgresException: '42P07: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists'` was also thrown. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for you are getting the exception is because the table `AspNetRoles` already exists in the database.

You can use the following code to check if there are any pending migrations and if there are any then execute the `MigrateAsync()` method:

```
var pendingMigrations = await context.Database.GetPendingMigrationsAsync();

if (pendingMigrations.Any())
{
    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
}
```

Read more about applying migrations automatically here: https://makolyte.com/ef-core-apply-migrations-programmatically/

**Update based on comments**

A good resource for getting started with migrations: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations

Comment: I tried it but the exception is still throwing at ```await context.Database.MigrateAsync();```.

Comment: What pending migrations do you have?

Comment: I just dropped all the Identity tables from the database and migrate. The tables were created but the exception was still being thrown.

Comment: Are you using the package manager console in visual studio to create the migrations? Is it the same exception that you are receiving?

Comment: I'm not using the package manage console. I'm trying to migrate programmatically. Actually, I was following this [link](https://github.com/thomasduft/openiddict-ui). I just used PostgreSQL instead of SQLite.

Comment: I understand, but the error is telling that you are trying to apply migrations that have already been applied to the database. The convention is to use the package manager in visual studio by first running the "Add-Migration" command and then run the "Update-Database" command. The ``MigrateAsync()`` method does not check if there are differences in the migrations, it just tries to apply all of them.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a good resource on how to get started with migrations.

Comment: Thanks. Migration via package manager works. Don't know what am I doing wrong with ```MigrateAsync()```.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve by using ``MigrateAsync()``?

Comment: It's just that I don't want to migrate manually after every changes.